# syntax error in conditional expression with bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I am running the below script :

```
status="UNKNOWN"
while [[ "$status" != "OUTPUT"]]; do
    echo "Checking
    status of job $jobid" status=$(zowe zos-jobs view job-status-by-jobid "$jobid" --rff status --rft string)
    echo "Current status is $status"
    sleep 5s
done;
```

all the time I am getting errors like : 
  syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'

I tried allot of combinations to solve this issue but every time I am getting different error .

PS : I am running on  PowerShell of windows

Comment: Add a space before the closing `]]` (and maybe after).

Answer (score 1):

When I am writing bash scripts I use `shellcheck` to check, if there are any syntax errors etc. You can either install it via `apt-get install shellcheck` or you use the [shellcheck website](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

I pasted your script there and it gives following output:

```
Line 2:
while [[ "$status" != "OUTPUT"]]; do
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this while loop.
      ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.
                                ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ]].
                                ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Try to fix the mentioned stuff from the output.

Comment: Thank you , I resolved this :status="UNKNOWN"
while [ "$status" != "OUTPUT" ]; do    
 echo "Checking status of job $jobid" 
 status=$(zowe zos-jobs view job-status-by-jobid "$jobid" --rff status --rft string)
 echo "Current status is $status"
 sleep 10s
done